# SQL Error : The multi-part identifier ... could not be bound

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm currently stuck in this problem in SQL Server and couldn't figure out where the problem is.

I'm using stored procedure for the following code :

```
DECLARE @cSql nVARCHAR(1000)

SET @cSql = 'SELECT  
            [A].[REC_ID], 
            [A].[ADJUSTMENT_REC_ID], 
            [A].[ITEM_REC_ID], 
            [B].[CODE] [ITEM_CODE],
            [B].[ALIAS_NAME] [ITEM_NAME], 
            [A].[WAREHOUSE_REC_ID], 
            [C].[CODE] [WAREHOUSE_CODE], 
            [C].[NAME] [WAREHOUSE_NAME], 
            [A].[qty_before_basic_uom], 
            [A].[qty_before_uom_1], 
            [A].[qty_adjust_basic_uom], 
            [A].[qty_adjust_uom_1], 
            [A].[qty_after_basic_uom], 
            [A].[qty_after_uom_1], 
            [A].[basic_uom], 
            [A].[uom_1], 
            [A].[ADJUST_VALUE], 
            [A].[cogs_adjust], 
            [A].[cogs_adjust_total], 
            [A].[asset_account_rec_id], 
            [A].[debit_account_rec_id],
            [A].[credit_account_rec_id], 
            [A].[remark], 
            [A].[record_version], 
            [A].[void_status], 
            [A].[void_reason], 
            [A].[void_datetime], 
            [A].[void_user_rec_id], 
            [A].[create_datetime], 
            [A].[create_user_rec_id], 
            [A].[edit_datetime],
            [A].[edit_user_rec_id], 
            [A].[delete_datetime], 
            [A].[delete_user_rec_id] 
            INTO [' + @cTemp + '] 
            FROM [IM_trsInventoryAdjustment_Detail] [A] 
            JOIN [IM_mstInventoryItem] [B] ON
               [B].[REC_ID] = [A].[item_rec_id] 
            JOIN [IM_mstWarehouse] [C] ON
               [C].[REC_ID] = [A].[warehouse_rec_id] 
            WHERE 1=0;'

EXEC sp_executeSQL @cSql
```

And as soon as I executed the query, SQL Server springs up **"The multi-part identifier"** error on every single column.

Could you help me locate where my mistake is, please??

P.S. I'm using dynamic query since the temporary table that I'm injecting the data to will keep on changing...

Comment: I'd suggest that you replace EXEC with PRINT and see what the query comes out to finallly?

Comment: Don't think you need both `EXEC` and `sp_executeSQL`...

Comment: Does it work at all? without dynamic part.

Comment: Also, having [ ] around anything is unecessary and cluttering.

Comment: @DhruvJoshi Holy... Turns out the problem is because my cSQL variable is not having enough length. Thanks for the heads up!! Appreciate it!

Comment: @Tobb yea? but once i tried using only EXEC it springs up error, dunno why though. But, thanks for the input man.

Comment: @IvanStarostin yeah it works big time. Pretty useful for flexible table names.

Comment: @JeHa then I guess this is a length issue: your string overflows 1000 symbols in some cases. Also in such a concatenation you better always cast first literal to required length e.g. `@mylongstr = cast('' as varchar(2500)) + 'some string parts'`- otherwise in the middle of concatenations the max legth (automatically evaluated) could be less then you need and string will be cut.

Comment: @JeHa I'd suggest that since your query is resolved, you should accept your own answer and logically close the question or delete the question altogether. Since it is tough to self-lose points, I'd personally recommend the former approach. However you can still gain the Disciplined badge if you chose to remove your question. :)

Comment: @DhruvJoshi how do i close the question??? I'm a little bit new to this though, i'm sure you've realized it. haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Holy, turns out the only problem is that my variable is not long enough to contain the whole command.

Here's the result when i replace EXEC with PRINT :

```
SELECT  
        [A].[REC_ID], 
        [A].[ADJUSTMENT_REC_ID], 
        [A].[ITEM_REC_ID], 
        [B].[CODE] [ITEM_CODE],
        [B].[ALIAS_NAME] [ITEM_NAME], 
        [A].[WAREHOUSE_REC_ID], 
        [C].[CODE] [WAREHOUSE_CODE], 
        [C].[NAME] [WAREHOUSE_NAME], 
        [A].[qty_before_basic_uom], 
        [A].[qty_before_uom_1], 
        [A].[qty_adjust_basic_uom], 
        [A].[qty_adjust_uom_1], 
        [A].[qty_after_basic_uom], 
        [A].[qty_after_uom_1], 
        [A].[basic_uom], 
        [A].[uom_1], 
        [A].[ADJUST_VALUE], 
        [A].[cogs_adjust], 
        [A].[cogs_adjust_total], 
        [A].[asset_account_rec_id], 
        [A].[debit_account_rec_id],
        [A].[credit_account_rec_id], 
        [A].[remark], 
        [A].[record_version], 
        [A].[void_status], 
        [A].[void_reason], 
        [A].[void_datet
```

So this is what i did. I changed :

```
DECLARE @cSQL NVARCHAR(1000)
```

to

```
DECLARE @cSQL NVARCHAR(4000)
```

and it works, big time. The error is gone, and I can continue to deal with another bugs now.

Thank for the comments and inputs!!

Comment: You could also use NVARCHAR(max), then the same problem won't reoccur if your query grows ;)

Comment: Make sure `@cTemp` variable has unique name in each session the query is executed